# Why is header image shifting

Tags: image, html

I've built a simple one-page site, and can't figure out why the header image is a bit further to the left on the home page compared to the other pages. Here's the link:
http://www.aptcoweb.com/dev/SEF-PC/index.htm

Comment: remove the padding on your img

Answer (score 0):

No, it wasn't the padding. It was the scroll bars, needed on the home page but not needed on the shorter pages. I added this to the css:

html {overflow-y:scroll}

and the problem was gone.